the sink writer always stopped or error after 1-3 times success?
I am using sink Writer to write sample which get from desktop duplication.
but it will stopped or error after 1-3 times success and here is the code:
while(true){
hr = dxgiOutputDuplication->AcquireNextFrame(0, &frame_info, &resource);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    ID3D11Texture2D* texture = NULL;
    hr = resource->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&texture);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        IDXGISurface* dxgiSurface = NULL;
        hr = texture->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGISurface), (void**)&dxgiSurface);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            IMFSample* sample = NULL;
            hr = MFCreateSample(&sample);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                IMFMediaBuffer* buffer = NULL;
                hr = MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer(__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), dxgiSurface, 0, FALSE, &buffer);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                    hr = sample->AddBuffer(buffer);
                    hr = sample->SetSampleDuration(duration);
                    hr = presentation->GetTime(&sampleTime);
                    hr = sample->SetSampleTime(sampleTime);
                    //sampleTime += duration * 10;

                    DWORD length = 0;
                    IMF2DBuffer* imf_buffer = NULL;
                    hr = buffer->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IMF2DBuffer), (void**)&imf_buffer);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                        hr = imf_buffer->GetContiguousLength(&length);
                        hr = buffer->SetCurrentLength(length);

                        hr = writer->WriteSample(0, sample);

                        if (FAILED(hr)) {
                            OutputDebugString(L"FAILED WRITE SAMPLE\n");
                        }

                        o++;
                        if (o > 1920) {
                            writer->Finalize();

                            OutputDebugString(L"OOOOOOOOOO");
                            break;
                        }
                        imf_buffer->Release();
                        imf_buffer = NULL;
                    }

                    buffer->Release();
                    buffer = NULL;
                }
                sample->Release();
                sample = NULL;
            }
            dxgiSurface->Release();
            dxgiSurface = NULL;
        }
        texture->Release();
        texture = NULL;
    }
    resource->Release();
    resource = NULL;
}
dxgiOutputDuplication->ReleaseFrame();
}

forgive the if else code I just use it for test. I should use THROW_IF_ERROR
and if you want the example code here it is :https://github.com/ljzj2/testdemo1

0 as timeout for AcquireNextFrame is bad, use something like 500, 1000  Also desktop duplication as the name says is a duplication API (not a screenshot API). If nothing changes at video level, nothing will be duplicated. Your repo link is dead

the repo link is fixed. thank you

The API is not going to work this way. You cannot add Desktop Duplication API texture directly as input for Sink Writer API: the texture is ephemeral. You need to make a copy first and feed the Sink Writer pipeline with the copy.

I have fixed as you told me. and yes it will not failed unexpectedly. but the wmv file is all of black .

You probably don't copy it right. Also, you should enable debug layer for Direct3D to receive hints about tings you do wrong.

Start from checking texture desc here to make sure that you are aware what texture you are creating, you probably need to remove some flags from the mode desc you are using.

I remove the miscFlags to 0 and it seems work. but still the time is not right. which sometimes plays faster and sometimes slower. the way I am using is wrong?
